# Testing for zero inflation and overdispersion in count time series data?

Tags: zero-inflation

How can I test whether my data is really zero inflated? Can I use the same methods as for count data?

Thank you.

Comment: 'Can I use the same methods as for count data?'  - could you perhaps explain to us what type of data is in your time series?

Comment: My data is a count time series data. How can I test for overdispersion?